# Javascript event 'onclick' not rendering result when the Javascript function is placed in HTML header section

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to run a simple Javascript code which changes the background color of the element on button click. Below is the code but it doesn't work. Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>check</title>
        
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        
            
        function checkRun(){
            var btn = document.querySelector('button');
            btn.onclick = function() {
                 btn.style.backgroundColor='red';
            }
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

        <input type='text' name='checkName' id='check1' value='val1' class='class1'/><br><br>
        <button type='button' name='checkName' id='check3' value='val3' class='class3'>Hello</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Whereas the below code works but I do not want to use the events in HTML attributes.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>check</title>
        
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        
            
        function checkRun(){
            var btn = document.querySelector('button');
            
                 btn.style.backgroundColor='red';
            
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

        <input type='text' name='checkName' id='check1' value='val1' class='class1'/><br><br>
        <button type='button' name='checkName' id='check3' value='val3' class='class3' onclick='checkRun()'>Hello</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Below is the code but it doesn't work. Please help.

Because **you haven't invoked** this method.

You need to invoke it on `DOMContentLoaded` event once the DOM is loaded.

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", checkRun );
```

Just place this code in the same script tag.

**Demo**

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>check</title>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function checkRun() {
      var btn = document.querySelector('button');
      btn.onclick = function() {
        btn.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", checkRun);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type='text' name='checkName' id='check1' value='val1' class='class1' /><br><br>
  <button type='button' name='checkName' id='check3' value='val3' class='class3'>Hello</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine!! However the answers provided by other users work too. Which is the best practice?

Comment: **Best practice** may depend upon in what context you are going to use it in a real use case. You can search for differences between `window.onload` vs `document.addEventListener`, etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method so that it works in your script write this line

```
checkRun();
```

look at the example below

```js
function checkRun(){
            var btn = document.querySelector('button');
            btn.onclick = function() {
                 btn.style.backgroundColor='red';
            }
        }
checkRun()
```

```html
<input type='text' name='checkName' id='check1' value='val1' class='class1'/><br><br>
        <button type='button' name='checkName' id='check3' value='val3' class='class3'>Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke your `checkRun()` function.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>check</title>

    <script type='text/javascript'>


        function checkRun(){
            var btn = document.querySelector('button');
            btn.onclick = function() {
                 btn.style.backgroundColor='red';
            }
        }
        
        window.onload= checkRun;

    </script>

</head>

<body>

        <input type='text' name='checkName' id='check1' value='val1' class='class1'/><br><br>
        <button type='button' name='checkName' id='check3' value='val3' class='class3'>Hello</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put it inside window onload function and remove checkrun function. it will work

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>check</title>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

  window.onload = function(){
       
            var btn = document.querySelector('button');
            btn.onclick = function() {
                 btn.style.backgroundColor='red';
            }
        
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

        <input type='text' name='checkName' id='check1' value='val1' class='class1'/><br><br>
        <button type='button' name='checkName' id='check3' value='val3' class='class3'>Hello</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to invoke `checkRun` method when document is ready

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
        checkRun();
    });

    function checkRun() {
        var btn = document.querySelector('button');
        btn.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

    }

 </script>
```

if you are using `Jquery` you can also do

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function () {
checkRun();

function checkRun() {
    var btn = document.querySelector('button');
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

}
});

</script>
```